# Why does HackerRank say code using short-circuiting boolean logic has a "runtime error"?

Tags: bash

I am taking my first steps in bash, looking into some simple challenges. 
I was working on some if..else statements like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

read a
read b
if [[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]]; then
    echo "a is greater"
elif [[ "$a" -lt "$b" ]]; then
    echo "b is greater"
else
    echo "equal"
fi
```

I had previously seen  the use of double ampersands to write such statements, but when I tried the following it returned "Runtime Error".

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

read a 
read b
[[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]] && echo "a is greater"
[[ "$a" -lt "$b" ]] && echo "b is greater"
[[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]] && echo "equal"
```

Could someone elaborate why the second way is wrong and, also, give some insight on which way should be preferred?

Thanks

Comment: The second way *is not* wrong in and of itself. That said... which shell are you running it with? `[[` is not guaranteed to be supported by `sh`, only `bash`. If you run `sh yourscript` or start it with `#!/bin/sh`, it isn't guaranteed to successfully parse that syntax.

Comment: "runtime error" doesn't sound like a bash error. Can you [edit] your question and include the actual error message? How do you run the script? Which version of bash?

Comment: Note that the two scripts are not actually equivalent. `elif` doesn't execute at all if the previous `if` executed. So you're doing extra conditionals that you don't need to do in the first version.

Comment: BTW, if you *are* writing bash-only code (and running it with bash as your shell), consider `if (( a > b )); then` instead of using `[[ ]]`; clearer to use explicit arithmetic syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
@CharlesDuffy I am using bash by passing 
``` #! /usr/bin/env bash ```  -will edit it in question- . 
@Robert To run it I am using the editor provided by ([hackerank](https://www.hackerrank.com/)), which returns the compiler message "Runtime Error" without any other messages.

Comment: @marlin_000, that's the shebang; how are you actually running the script? If you use `sh yourscript`, then the shebang is ignored.

Comment: Oh. HackerRank's "Runtime Error" may just mean that `$?` is nonzero at the end of the script. That's not exactly a real error... but you can suppress it by putting an `exit 0` on the end.

Comment: great, `exit 0` did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit status of a script is the exit status of the last command it runs.

When your last command is:

```
[[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]] && echo "equal"
```

...then if the values are *not* numerically equal, that command short-circuits after the first component, which has a nonzero exit status.

By contrast, when your last command is:

```
echo "a is greater"
```

...then there's no unsuccessful command to set a nonzero value in `$?`.

---

One way to make your code more equivalent to the original formulation would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read a 
read b
[[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]] && { echo "a is greater"; exit; }
[[ "$a" -lt "$b" ]] && { echo "b is greater"; exit; }
[[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]] && { echo "equal"; exit; }
```

...or, less equivalent but less wordily, just adding an `exit 0` onto the end.